# looping loops in ruby (noob)

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

```
n = 0
m = 40
o = 0
while n < m 
n = n + 1
end
while n = m 
o = o + 1 
n = 0 
end
```

With that code, what would be the best way to make it so once it went through the second loop it would go back through the first???

Any help for this beginner is welcomed. :)

Comment: You mean like just putting the code for the first loop after the second one?

Comment: yes-- minus the copying and pasting.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? (the code seems weird, having a while loop than depends on m, yet setting n to 0.

Comment: It seems like you want to factor that out into a function, and call it from both places.

Comment: What I want to do is to have one loop happen after another one runs its course. Once the second while has happened (and n is back to 0) I want n to go back to 40 making o = 2, than 3 than 4 etc.

I hope thats clearer

Comment: Can you say why you're doing this, rather than how you're trying to do it?  There might be a Ruby way cut through the confusion and let the language do most of the work, if only we know the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
n = 0
m = 40
o = 0
while n < m 
  n = n + 1
  if (n == m) {
    o = o + 1
    n = 0
  }
  // as pointed out by Samir, you might want to put
  // termination condition here, else it will loop infinitely
end
```

Comment: That code will loop infinitely. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure you've given us enough information to solve this one.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

It would be unusual to use while like this in Ruby.  There are lots of better ways to iterate.  For example, if you are walking through an array, you can do:

```
my_array.each do |e|
   # e is the next element of my_array
end
```

If you are walking through a string, you can do:

```
my_string.each_char do |c|
   # c is the next character in my_string
end
```

If you really want a counter, you can use each_with_index for an array, or for a string:

```
(1..my_string.size).each do |i|
   c = my_string[i - 1]
   # now c = next character, i = index
end
```

Not a direct answer to your question, I admit, but DJ & DigitalRoss are correct, you seem to be working towards nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

#### Nested loops, maybe?

Are you looking for something like this:

```
(0..2).each do |o|
  (0..4).each do |n|
    p [o, n]
  end
end
```

Adjust the loop boundaries as you like...